# Dynamically rendering polygon, point, and line features

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, wfs, rendering

I have a Feature Collection consisting of features having id, color_code, etc as attributes. I have to render this feature with the color in the color_code attribute. Is this possible and please suggest some links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You should build and use a renderer, probably a [unique value renderer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi/uniquevaluerenderer.htm).

Before adding your feature layer to a map, loop through your features and build symbols from your color codes and [add them to a renderer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi/uniquevaluerenderer.htm#addValue). Then use [setRenderer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi/featurelayer.htm#setRenderer) to specify your renderer for your layer. The [unique value renderer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples/renderer_unique_value.html) sample will probably be helpful.